# Intermittent communication issues with Office 365 (Exchange Online)

Tags: microsoft-office-365

Four or five users (out of 30-35 users) at one of our office locations are having odd issues with Outlook 2010 and 2013 losing the connection to Office 365: Occasionally, when sending an email, the progress bar goes almost all the way to completed but then stays there.
If I open "Connection Status," the connections are all established but the Req/Fail counter doesn't increase. But if I open the connection monitor on my firewall, I can see TCP traffic to the Microsoft server slowly trickle across.
Cancelling the server request immediately fixes the issue (as will restarting Outlook) but only for that Send/Receive.
I'm using Cisco switches with a SonicWall TZ205 firewall. I was hoping the issue was caused by our firewall killing inactive RPC tunnels, but upping the TCP timeout to two hours has had no effect.
Microsoft hasn't been any help and they've stopped returning our phone calls.
If it is a local network issue, what would I even look for?

Comment: Do you have any kind of content filter or outbound proxy between the clients and O365?

Comment: None. We don't filter any outbound traffic.

Comment: Outlook 2010 is not supported, upgrade asap. Especially with M365 its important to keep up with the latest versions. Microsoft will soon start blocking Outlook 2010 :https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-will-soon-block-outlook-2010-and-earlier-from-connecting-to-microsoft-365-exchange-servers/

Comment: @Ace I asked this question in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Try disable IPV6 on the host or the Router.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852

Comment: IPv6 is not used on this network. It's disabled on the workstation and the router doesn't even support it.